# Transform text like an arch

Tags: text, text-wrap, affinity-designer

In Photoshop you can use the wrap-text tool to shape the text **arch** like ([More here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/key-concepts/warp.html)). In Affinity-Designer you can create a text on a curve but that does not the same like the arch option in Photoshop. Is there a feature in Affinity-Designer?

In Photoshop (*Art*="Type", *Torbogen*="Arch"):
[image: In Photoshop]
In Affinity-Designer
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affinity Designer doesn't have it. Its sister application Affinity Photo has Mesh Warp, which includes also this - only has a 1x1 mesh and can drag the edges or corner handles. This is a screenshot of Affinity Photo:

[image]

Unfortunately the result will no longer be editable text, it's a raster image.

Probably Affinity Designer will eventually get it too because its predecessors Serif Draw and Serif PagePlus had it. Its name was "Envelope" in Draw. In PagePlus it was "Mesh Warp". In both old applications' text stayed editable after the deformation.

Comment: I ended up creating the text in Photoshop and imported it into Affinity. Does Illustrator or Inkscape have this feature?

Comment: @Colin Illustrator has it (Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Arc, positive horizontal bending + positive vertical distortion. Inkscape has it, too but you must convert the text to path and apply a path effects (=tricky, the same as in Affinity D. comes out easily)